# How to implement a simple website counter for myself?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have a website , where I like to keep a count which is pseudo-private. By "pseudo-private" , I mean it will be an un-linked URL somewhere in my site. And just use by me(think diet or exercise-counter).

I want it to look like this. 2 web-pages, one has a simple count, and is static and simple like so:

[image]
"

And then I want to make a separate page where I modify that count, like so:

[image]

What I'm curious about is this : would I need some simple database to do this? Or is it a simple JavaScript thing?

Perhaps I can find sample guestbook code, and mod. it (but I really really want a clean simple page) ?   I'm not askin for free-code, just pointers about how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to read and edit an integer value you can just store it in a text file.

Comment: hmm, Ok this may work. we'll still need an "edit" website though, that would be simple javascript? thanks!